# How do I add a Message to a function in Angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular2-forms

I am trying to add a message to this function below, when `sendPasswordResetEmail` is completed

I have this code below

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
var emailAddress = "user@example.com";
auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress).then(function() {

  // Email sent.(How do i add a message here saying email sent?)

}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Comment: You want to show the message where? in the console?

Comment: Use JavaScript native `alert` or add a popup template and make it visible by adding class names here.

Comment: @BeetleJuice i want to bind a message and the display in html

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah you got any popup template demonstration please?

Comment: [This](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/minimal-modal-window-with-plain-javascript/) and [this](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/simple-clean-popup-window-with-pure-javascript-simple-popup/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nnrXD/) amy help you